# What does it mean for bones to be bleaching?

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

What does it exactly mean to say bones are bleaching? Specifically, does it mean

```
their color is getting whiter
```

or

```
they are moldering
```

A context:

> Since then I have lived to see state after state extirpate its wolves. I have watched the face of many a newly wolfless mountain, and seen the south-facing slopes wrinkle with a maze of new deer trails. I have seen every edible bush and seedling browsed, first to anaemic desuetude, and then to death. I have seen every edible tree defoliated to the height of a saddlehorn. Such a mountain looks as if someone had given God a new pruning shears, and forbidden Him all other exercise. In the end the starved bones of the hoped-for deer herd, dead of its own too-much, **bleach** with the bones of the dead sage, or molder under the high-lined junipers.

[Thinking Like a Mountain](http://www.eco-action.org/dt/thinking.html)

Comment: What reason do you have for thinking it does not mean to become white?

Comment: @StoneyB Because 1) they are already white and 2) while it makes sense to say bones are moldering, what is the point in saying bones are becoming white?

Comment: I think it's referring to the herd, not the bones. So the herd is becoming white from the bones.

Comment: You've been posting lots of excerpts from this text. He clearly writes in a very archaic manner, and with lots of poetic imagery. Trying to understand him literally just seems wrong.

Comment: @Barmar What do you mean the herd is becoming white from the bones? Clearly the subject of the verb "bleach" is starved bones.

Comment: I think it's referring to "hoped-for deer herd". What do you think "dead of its own too-much" refers to?

Comment: The bones are bleaching in the sun -- becoming whiter.  They are decaying in the damper shade of the juniper, which is a tree.  (The juniper will also drop organic matter on the bones.) I compliment you on reading Aldo Leopold, and on your interest in ecological balance.  Contrary to what @Balmar suggests, I think you should take what he says literally.  Looking up words like bleach, molder and sage will help you and enable you to ask more pointed questions.

Comment: @ab2 I had looked up "bleach", "molder", and "sage". Their meanings are are clear. The question is however about the *meaning in context.* In that respect, my question is pointed.

Comment: Bones from a freshly-dead animal will be covered with various protein substances and will be generally be a dirty brown color.  As the rain and sun and mice and microbes work on the bones and eat away the protein, the remaining calcium bone material shows through as white.  This is typically referred to as "bleaching".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Bleaching"—or more accurately, "whitening"—is a natural process that exposed bones and other materials undergo in certain climates. Here is a brief description of how this works, from "[What Is Whitening and Why Do It?](https://bonedork.tumblr.com/whitening)" posted on the bonedork site on tumblr:

> The natural whitening process [of bones] is a collaboration between time and the elements. Ultraviolet (UV) radiation, which comes from sunlight, is a big player in this process.
>
> The energy in UV radiation causes the degradation and eventual breakdown of many of the organic compounds that will stain bone tissue. As the molecules in the stains absorb solar energy, their electrons become excited and the bonds between atoms are more likely to break. Naturally, this means that in places where the sunlight is more intense, such as deserts, there will be more UV energy to break the bonds in the staining molecules and the bones will whiten much faster. It is possible to find perfectly, naturally bleached bones in less extreme climates, but, just as with degreasing, the bones are likely to be destroyed before the process completes.

The choice of the word "bleaching" for this process undoubtedly owes a great deal to an imperfect analogy to clothes bleaching (which typically involves the use of a hydrogen chloride solution). Indeed, the term "sun bleaching" is widely used to describe the effect of sun exposure in lightening everything from human hair to clothing.

The bonedork site points out, however, that attempting to artificially replicate natural bone bleaching by soaking bones in chlorine bleach will not work:

> **IMPORTANT!!!** While whitening is often referred to as “bleaching”, **please bear in mind that the only safe thing to whiten bones with is hydrogen peroxide**. Chlorine bleach is damaging to all body tissues, including bone! Bone tissue is also extremely porous, and bleach will seep into it like water into a sponge. It will break down the molecules of the bone tissue itself, resulting in **fragile**, crumbling bones that will eventually turn to dust.

In the deserts of Arizona and Utah, I have seen bones and, somewhat relatedly, deer antlers (which are composed of fused hair, not bone) that have been sun-bleached to a ghostly white. It's easy to see why the term "bleaching" caught on to describe the whitening that such relics have undergone.

Answer (score 1):

Bleached bones are weathered laying in the sun and all weather of course. Bone is primarily white and "yellows" and "greys" as it ages exposed to the elements; nutrients leech out and the color changes. This actually occurs differently depending on location i.e. in the north bone trends to be on the off-white/ "grey" where mid climates "yellowing" (Ive no experience in other climates).

Comment: Hi @Andy Sayer, please indicate where this information comes from. Questions on ELU should ideally include some cited sources to back up the information being provided. Thanks!